# Why is the LED output by default high with the PCA9633LED driver?

Tags: led-driver

I'm using the LED driver PCA9633 (8-pin.) After reboot, with default settings, the output of the LED pins are high, turning the LEDs on at reboot.

1. Is there a good reason why I should want this?
2. Is there a similar chip with default output state low?

Relevant default values:

- SLEEP = 1 (low power mode, oscillator off)
- INVRT = 0 (output logic state not inverted, value to use when no external driver used)
- OUTDRV = 1 (LED outputs are configured with a totem pole structure)
- LEDOUT = 00000000 (LED driver is off)

The 8-pin version doesn't have an OE pin.

The datasheet states:

If LEDOUT = 00, INVRT = 0, and OUTDRV = 1, LED state = VDD.

I'm using 12V LEDs, connected as shown at LED3 of the typical application:

[image: typical application pca9633]

I don't want to turn off the LEDs immediately after startup, the peak current at startup might cause problems. I'd like to avoid using additional hardware inverting the output signal.

Comment: Could you flip the LED's around and low side switch them instead? Then, the default state would be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing the chip with a PCA9632 solved this problem. It's almost the same chip as the PCA9633, but the default value of OUTDRV = 0. The LED output is by default High-Z.

Answer (score 2):

You would normally connect the LEDs with a current-limiting resistor from the output to Vdd, so output = Vdd is 'off'. From the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.ca/datasheet/2/302/PCA9633-3139106.pdf):

[image]

Comment: This will not work for me, as I'm using 12V LEDs connected as shown at LED3. I will add this information to my question, thank you.

Comment: In that case, you're scuppered since the reset condition of INVRT  is 0 and no OE pin. You would need an extra inverter or a high-side driver per pin or some other additional circuitry. If you use a ULN2803 you can get 4 drivers and 4 inverters in one package (one additional quad resistor network required for pullups).

Comment: Thank you, I will consider replacing the chip.